# Testing localhost WordPress site over LAN with iPad, iPhone

Tags: php, wordpress, ipad, xampp, localhost

I am developing a Wordpress theme that requires testing with multiple devices over my local network. I use the localhost server XAMPP which runs apache on port 80.

When I access my PC's IP (192.168.0.16) port 80 using an iPad, it returns the apache directory of which I have two sites:

1. site1
2. wordpress

The first site is a basic php site, this loads perfectly.
The second site is Wordpress, and won't let me access it (see pic).

I have tried changing the setting inside Wordpress:

- changing localhost to 192.168.0.16 inside the site and Wordpress address.

Can anyone advise me on what I'm doing wrong?

[image]
[image]

Comment: rename .htaccess file to htaccess.txt. Also go under Settings > General and change your Site Address to `http://localhost/wordpress` and `http://localhost/wordpress` in this order

Also locate and edit `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`  to add this line: `192.168.0.16     localhost`

Comment: This hasn't worked, renaming the .htaccess file broke my site links with 404 error and still didn't allow access from the iPad/iPhone.

Comment: go to permalink section and make them non-friendly links like `?p=123`